# Commutators in bra-ket notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator

2-d Hilbert space, with 2 (orthogonal) kets $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$

Operator $A=|a\rangle\langle b| + |b\rangle\langle a| $

Operator $B=-i|a\rangle\langle b| +i|b\rangle\langle a| $

Commutator $[A,B]=AB-BA$

When I try to compute the commutator I end up getting expressions like $|a\rangle\langle a| $ , i.e a ket multiplied by a bra. How am I meant to calculate this?

Comment: If the operators are already a multiplication of a bra with a ket, why does it trouble you that the resulting commutator (which has the same nature as its constituent elements) is of the same kind?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are just two of the Pauli matrices, and you (should) know their commutation relations. From that, you can find directly the result, and write it in the $a,b$ basis (to verify your direct calculation).

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel This still leaves the question of if he is supposed to simplify further. He should have two terms like that in his answer and it can't be simplified further.

Comment: @Adam I would think whether or not he should know the commutation relations of pauli matrices depends on whether or not he has been taught them. My guess is that this is the beginning of a course on QM and this is a simple exercise in bra-ket notation, which usually comes before spin and pauli matrices.

Comment: Yes I am just starting a course on QM. So there is no way to simplify further a bra times a ket?

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs: Yes, you're right. But wikipedia is at the next corner, and in few weeks/months, my comment might shed a different light on this exercise. It was not supposed to be the answer to the question.

Comment: @user1887919: as Ignacio was saying, why do you think that   $|a\rangle\langle a|$ should be simplified more ? How would you write an arbitrary operator in the $a,b$ basis ?

Comment: It just didn't feel neat finishing with this term. Does it make sense to say that when considered as a matrix multiplication of a column by a row, this gives another matrix, whereas bra * ket gives a single number, which is why they dont simplify in the same way?

Comment: @user1887919: yes, exactly. A matrix is an application that takes a vector on its right and give another vector. That's exactly what $|i\rangle\langle j|$ is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is alright, there is no way to further simplify expressions (operators) like $|a\rangle\langle a|,|b\rangle\langle a|,|b\rangle\langle b|,|a\rangle\langle b| $. You could write linear combinations of them as matrix in the basis of the states $a$ and $b$, but that is no simplification, but a matter for notation. Your final result should be:

$$\left[A,B \right]=2 i\,|a\rangle\langle a|+2 i\,|b\rangle\langle b|$$

Comment: And that links with the Pauli matrices mentioned above! Perfect thank you